# How to use firebase.initializeApp (WITHOUT Angularfire) in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase

Most of the suggestions are to do it in `app.module.ts`, right before `@NgModule({})` (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852003/where-do-i-add-firebase-initializeapp-in-my-angular-7-project) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852003/where-do-i-add-firebase-initializeapp-in-my-angular-7-project) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563140/error-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-app-initiali) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595467/firebase-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-app-initi) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805209/error-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created)) or to do it within the top level `AppComponent`'s constructor. For example:

```js
//app.module.ts
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
```

The reason why I think it is a good approach is because I can have access to the same firebase instance from multiple services. However, despite having successfully using this method in 1 of my apps, I am not able to replicate the desire behavior from any other apps. Particularly, when trying to access the `firebase` instance from a service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const auth = firebase.auth();

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor() {
        //Try accessing the current user, should return null or the user
        //It could be any function, I'm jusing using this as an example
        console.log(auth.currentUser);
    }
}
```

I always receive an error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

What is the proper way to initialize firebase app so that all the services can have access to the same firebase instance? Preferably without relying on creating a new Service just to handle that.

Comment: It seems like the code in the second snippet doesn't import `app.module.ts`, which means that `firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)` doesn't run.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Thank you for the respond, but I'm still a bit confused. Isn't `app.module.ts` the top module that will be executed anyway (because it boots the app)? How exactly do I "import" `app.module.ts` in a service? I have never heard of it before.